# Can I run a native OS installation as a virtual machine OS?

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, fedora

I am using win7. I wish to use Fedora on my machine, but don't know just how much I will be needing either of my OS. I wish to install Ferdora and configure it as a dual boot system.

At the same time, when time calls for it, I want to run the same Fedora installation as a virtual machine on top of win7. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Search the internet for Virtual Box by *sigh* Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

VMWare Workstation supports this, but I've never tried in Windows.

Here's an article on their site (it discusses VMWare 5 and they're now on 7.1, so a newer one can probably be unearthed):

http://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_disk_dualboot.html